# C# Google calendar api service.Events.Insert invalid Domain global

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api

When I try to call service.Events.Insert( myEvent, "primary" ) I get the following error:

```
The service calendar has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid Value [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]
```

myEvent contains these value:

```
Event myEvent = new Event
{
 Summary = summary,
 Description = description,
 Location = location,
 Id = id,
 Start = new EventDateTime( )
 {
  DateTime = startPoint,
  TimeZone = timeZoneName
 },
 End = new EventDateTime( )
 {
  DateTime = endPoint,
  TimeZone = timeZoneName
 }
};
```

What does this error mean?

Is there in Google a place to look why a particular exception was thrown?

I've searched my files and I don't specify GLOBAL anywhere.

Comment: PS: the values passed are:
Summary..:Jassmeisterschaft

Descripti:Some description

Id.......:040000008200e00074c5b7101a82e008000000002029c857722e10100000000000000001000000085238d740c7c544d96f796529c1c4244

Start....:12/6/2016 8:00:00

StartTZ..:(UTC+10:00) Brisbane

End......:12/6/2016 8:30:00

EndTZ....:(UTC+10:00) Brisbane

Location.:Perth

Comment: Are you correctly authenticated? Can you list all events on the primary calendar for example? Also, could you get the JSON request which is actually sent to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The error 400: Bad Request or user error.** This mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.
So make sure to provide the valid value for the methods.
Here is a [code example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples)  on how to properly set the values.

```
Event newEvent = new Event()
{
    Summary = "Google I/O 2015",
    Location = "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
    Description = "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
    Start = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00"),
        TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
    },
    End = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00"),
        TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
    },
```

> One more thing make sure your date format should be “yyyy-mm-dd”. It
>   is based on this
>   [page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

Answer (score 1):

Also if using Recurrence in the calendar entry, and specifying the 'Until' rule check it has a "z" at the end of the string.

```
UNTIL=20180117T235959Z
```

and not

```
UNTIL=20180117T235959
```